# How do I repeat a for loop only for n times?

Tags: loops, for-loop

I need to create a program that asks you for 'a' and 'b' and gives you only the first 10 even numbers between 'a' and 'b, skipping 8 (in case there is one).

So far I have accomplished to print the even number between 'a' and 'b' skipping 8 but I have no idea how to limit this loop to iterate only 10 times.

Here is the code:

```
def pares(x,y):
for num in range(x,y): 
    if num%2==0:
        if num == 8:
            continue
        print(num, end = ' ')
    
          
def main():
    a = int(input('Dame un entero A: '))
    b = int(input('Dame un entero B: '))
    b += 1
    pares(a,b)
    
main()
```

Comment: Have you considered creating, checking, and incrementing some type of counter in your loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a counter and terminate the loop when you reach 10.

```
counter = 0
for num in range(x,y): 
    if counter == 10:
        break
    else:
        if num%2==0:
            if num == 8:
                continue
            print(num, end = ' ')
            counter+= 1
```